# Algorithm to only draw what the camera sees?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rendering

I'm making a 3D FPS with OpenGL and here is the basics of how it works. The game is a 3D array of cubes. I know the location of the player's current cube, aswell as the camera x,y,z and I know the x, y, z rotation of the camera too. Right now I just make a square around the player and render this and then add distant fog. The problem though, is that I'm still rendering everything that the player is in back of. How could I selectively only render what the player sees, not render everything within an X radius as Iam doing now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about frustum culling, if i get you right. I suggest that you take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/viewfrustum/). They provide nice demos and explain everything in detail.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you need to look into [culling concepts](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1212.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Are the cubes rooms of a maze through which the player navigates? If so, and assuming the rooms are static over the course of the game, you could use a [BSP tree](http://www.gamers.org/dhs/helpdocs/bsp_faq.html) to traverse the scene in order of depth, stopping when you pass the player.